# Control Strip in Terminal could not be found

Tags: touch-bar

The Touch Bar from my Macbook Pro A1989 Touch 2018 13" after a display change is not working; not sure the display break was the cause. But I wanted to reset or restart it from the Activity Monitor, but could not find it there.

How can I find it to restart the process?

Comment: First thought would be a reassembly error. Can you see it in About This Mac > System Report… ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?